# I want to show data grouped by column name "RefPI" in C#. I have a datatable and how can do that

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a datatable in C# and now I want to show data which will be grouped by columname "ReferenceOfThePI". How can I show that. I have written a code but that is not working. Please help me.

//Below is the Current data in datatable:
    RefPI   Date1       Date2    Status1    Status2 Status3 Status4 
    C2-EP1  28/04/2020  5/5/2022
    C2-EP2  28/06/2022  1/5/2019
    C2-EP3  15/6/2019   6/5/2019
    C2-EP1                        OK                         OK
    C2-EP2                        ok           ok   data1
    C2-EP2                        yes          yes  yes

//Expected result
    RefPI    Date1        Date2  Status1 Status2 Status3 Status4
    C2-EP1 28/04/20 5/5/22 OK                             OK
    C2-EP2 28/06/22 1/5/19 ok        ok   data1
                                      yes     yes        yes
    C2-EP3  15/6/2019  6/5/2019

//My code is as below but is not working.

```
dtHist.Merge(dtMainPIHistoryRepeat);
int iRow = 0;
DataTable dtGrpby = null;
dtGrpby = dtHist.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(r => new
{
  Col1 = r["RefPI"],
  Col2 = r["Date1"],
  Col3 = r["Date2"],
  Col4 = r["Status1"],
  Col5 = r["Status2"],
  Col6 = r["Status3"],
  Col7 = r["Status4"],
  Col8 = r["Status5"]
})
.Select(g =>
 {
   var row = dtHist.NewRow();

   row["RefPI"] = g.Key.Col1;
   row["Date1"] = g.Key.Col2;
   row["Date2"] = g.Key.Col3;
   row["Status1"] = g.Key.Col4; ;
   row["Status2"] = g.Key.Col5; ;
   row["Status3"] = g.Key.Col6; ;
   row["Status4"] = g.Key.Col7; ;
   row["Status5"] = g.Key.Col8;

   return row;
   }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Is there anyway in Linq to groupby on a column on a datatable?

Comment: Want to group by on one key column(RefPI) in a  C# datatable.My table currently is:

RefPI Date1 Date2 Status1 Status2 Status3  C2-EP1 d1    d2
C2-EP2 d3    d4
C2-EP3 d6    d7
C2-EP1             OK       OK    No
C2-EP2             ok       st1   DATA1
C2-EP2             Good     yes   yes

//Expected result
RefPI Date1 Date2 Status1 Status2 Status3  C2-EP1 d1   d2       OK     OK     No
C2-EP2 d3   d4       ok     st1    DATA1
                     Good   yes    yes
C2-EP3 d6   d7

Above I wanted to group on C2-EP1,C2-EP2,C2-EP3.